# How to adapt image to button size?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the background image of my button adapt to the button's size? If my image is 2800x1300 how can I make it adapt to  a 1000x540 button? Please help a guy in need !

Comment: Do you want a button the size of the entire page? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: I have a button that is always 100% width and 431px Height.

Answer (score 2):

Really depends on the situation but maybe this will help:

`background-size: cover`

Or

`background-size: contain`

See what works best.

Comment: Thank you Rick! You Rock! ( See what I did there? rick-rock get it :)) )

Comment: Haha, no problem. Can you tag my answer as "the" answer? :p Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use : `background-size:cover;`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6pLp9b6/1/)

```css
.button {
  background: url(http://theimageconference.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/images-50x50.png) no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="button" class="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size:cover;`

> It Scales the background image to be as large as possible so that the
>   background area is completely covered by the background image. Some
>   parts of the background image may not be in view within the background
>   positioning area

To see how this exactly works go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)